# Show html tags as a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor

I'm making small html editor for my website.

[image]
**My editor**

```
<textarea class="editor"></textarea>
```

**Example window**

```
<div class="results"></div>
```

**Javascript and JQuery**

```
function textarea_post(){
    var text = $(".editor").val();
    text = text.replace(/<code>/g,"<pre>").replace(/<\/code>/g,"</pre>");
    $(".results").html(text);
}

$(".editor").on("keydown keyup paste",function(e){
    textarea_post();
});
```

My code replace `<code></code>` tags from editor with `<pre></pre>` tags.

The problem is that you can't do html code snippet between `<pre></pre>`.
Html code needs to be shown as a text not as html itself between `<pre></pre>`.

Outside `<pre></pre>` other tags needs to be shown as a html

Comment: Try to use `$(".results").text(text);` instead of `$(".results").html(text);`

Comment: I need to use `$(".results).html(text)` because other tags that are outside ´<pre></pre>´ needs to be shown as a html like my ´<h3>Example</h3>´

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I tested it with a few sample strings and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of what you are you are trying to do can be accomplished through css; your javascript seems to be fine; but your html needs slight adjustment as center tags are deprecated and not supported in html.

Have a look at this snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/1q6c8df7/1)  (just press enter at the end of the textarea)

EDIT: updated to include better script from Mohit, but note the center tags!

```js
function textarea_post() {
   var text = $(".editor").val();
    text = text.replace(/<code>/g,"<pre>").replace(/<\/code>/g,"</pre>");
    $(".results").html(text);
    $(".results pre").each(function(){
      var escapedText = $(this).html();
      $(this).text( escapedText );
    });
}

$(".editor").on("keydown keyup paste", function(e) {
 if (e.which==13){
  textarea_post();
  }
});
```

```css
textarea, .editor {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color:white;
  color:darkblue;
  margin-top:0;
  border-bottom:1px #000 dashed;
}
.results{background-color:lightgrey;
width:80vw;
border:1px solid;
overflow-y:scroll;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="editor">
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <code>
    function MyFunction(a, b){
     return a+b;
    }
    MyFunction(5, 10)
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </code>


</textarea>

<div class="results"></div>
```

Hope this helps - post a comment if this is not the desired effect/if i have misunderstood.

Comment: If you try write html code snippet between your `<code></code>` tags it disappears. example ´<code><em></em></code>´ it needs to show `<em></em>` tags as a text in results

Comment: If you slowly write the html code you can see that it post `<` as `&lt;` etc... I'm really stuck on this

Comment: @Tonza i think it's probably the best option.. the users will only want a code preview from time to time anyway, just post a note to press enter to preview

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```js
function textarea_post(){
    var text = $(".editor").val();
    text = text.replace(/<code>/g,"<pre>").replace(/<\/code>/g,"</pre>");
    $(".results").html(text);
    $(".results pre").each(function(){
      var escapedText = $(this).html();
      $(this).text( escapedText );
    });//
}

$(".editor").on("keydown keyup paste",function(e){
    textarea_post();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="editor" rows="15"></textarea>

<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: hmm yes, because only `<` is not considered a tag so may be it is not picked up by `.html()` as an element.

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line:

```
text = text.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
```

This replaces the `<` characters with `&lt;` that is the HTML variant for the less-than sign. It also replaces the `>` characters with `&gt;` that is the HTML variant for the greater-than sign

Comment: Yes that works but it only needs to replace tags that are inside <pre</pre>